# Trouble with launching node inside a screen session via PHP

Tags: php, node.js, shell-exec, gnu-screen, proc-open

So to start; I am trying to launch a node application via PHP. I created a script that can check if the node application is running, close it and start it. But I have some trouble with using screen with PHP.

Now before I carry on, comments about how I shouldn't do it won't help, I need to have it launched via PHP, due to it working alongside a website, and I want our client to be able to change settings, which will relaunch the application (unless you have another idea).

I am currently using the command:

```
screen -dmS NODEJS node main.js 121016
```

Now I can launch node, and get the output (as long as I add a process.exit somewhere so PHP/Node doesn't run forever). I am already in the correct directory also, I am using this code to launch it:

```
$out = shell_exec('screen -dmS NODEJS node main.js 121016');
var_dump($out);
```

But it is not creating the screen session. I have also tried:

```
$proc = proc_open('screen -dmS NODEJS node main.js 121016', $this->pipe_spec, $pipes);
```

I also tried to use `exec` and the back ticks but I am fairly certain the back ticks are the same as shell_exec?

Anyway I am completely lost, and am not sure what else I can do. I don't want node constantly running, which is why I want it to launch when you click save in the manager (in php), and then it closes/stops itself when it has completed it's tasks.

Any help would go a long way, I have spent hours trying to work it out, but I am getting no where... thanks anyway.

Comment: Why are you even trying to use screen?

Comment: Just use `exec('node main.js &');`

Comment: @JonStirling I am using screen, so that I can connect to the program in case anything goes wrong, due to it running alongside a website. Have you got a better way to do it? that allows me to send it commands also to stdin? As I need to send it commands also!

Comment: Hi @Philipp will this work on server hosting? I think they disable exec, would shell_exec work?

Comment: If they allow `shell_exec`, they also allow `exec` - but in case they don't, just replace `exec` with `shell_exec`

Comment: Thanks @Philipp, I tried using this, but how can I control the application? As in interact with it on a console level? Currently it can take commands, like sending :shutdown via stdin, which will safely close it? Is there a way to do this with your method?

Comment: You could stop the application with it's pid. To get the pid, you could run nginx like this `$pid = shell_exec("nohup nginx main.js > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!");` Using the pid, you could send any signal to the process. I.e. kill it `shell_exec("kill $pid");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144944/discussion-between-danny-smc-and-philipp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update on this for anyone interested.

The issue was caused because I wasn't managing the pipes correctly, and was not sending the stdOut pipe. The problem occurred mainly when I tried to remove screen as it was not giving me the correct PID.

An update on what I used in the end:

```
node main.js > /dev/null 2> logs/app-error.log & echo $!
```

The last one '2>' I was not managing correctly.